# Trying create a subclass object from the parent objects controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to figure out how I can grab the current instance of an object called "meal" to create a food object that belongs to it.

It works in console... its simple and goes like this:

```
user = User.first
user.meal.first.meal_foods.create
```

A user can have many meals, and each meal can have many meal_foods.

The challenge here for me is in the create action of the foods controller in creating my meals_food.

(I'm using STI here hence the "foods" controller and the "meal_food" name)

Currently the create action looks like this:

```
 @food = current_user.meal.meal_foods.build
```

I've also tried this because something pluralizing the objects name works

```
 @food = current_user.meal.meal_food.build
```

Here's the error it gives for both

```
undefined method `meal_foods' for [#<Meal id: 17, user_id: 1, meal_name: "Meal">]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

---

**Update:**

The issue I'm having here specifically is selecting the correct meal to create a meal_food for.

In console I can select the first one, which is fine. But in the foods controller, I need to *select the correct meal* for which to create a meal_food.

Writing meals.first would select the very first meal for that user. If I want to select the 3rd meal out of 5, I need to figure a way to grab that meal's id.

I've just tried this:

```
<%= link_to "new food", foods_path(id: meal.id), method: :create %>
```

to pass in the meal.id as a parameter that can be used in foods_controller. And then in the foods_controller I did:

```
@meal_food = current_user.meals.find_by_id(params[:id]).meal_foods.build
```

It *looks* like it's submitting because the page is reloaded with a success message, but the meal_food isn't created, so it just doesn't show up.

I checked in console, and there's no new food being created for this users first meal.

---

Ok I realized that the link_to I wrote above creates this url:

```
foods?id=29
```

and the method I'm using to retrieve this id isn't working because params[:id] is looking for a path id, not this url id.

Thanks in advance!

---

The Models:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :sanitize
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meal_foods
  attr_accessible :meal_name

  def sanitize
    self.meal_name = "Meal"
  end
end 


class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand, :carbs, :fat, :name, :protien, :type

end   

class MealFood < Food
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :meal, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :custom_foods, dependent: :destroy
```

The controllers:

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  #functions
  def create

    #this is where I need to grab the correct meal, and then create a meal_food for it...

    if @meal_food.save!
      flash[:success] = "Food created successfully!"
      redirect_to meal_path(current_user.id)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Food couldn't be created."
      redirect_to meal_path(current_user.id)
    end
 end
end
```

Partials:

Here's the meal partial that gets repeated to display each meal. It has the link_to for creating a meal that will belong to the meal it's under.

```
<tr>
  <thead class=meal-thead>
   <td class=meal-thead-name> <%= meal.meal_name %> </td>
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>
     <th> </th>
     <th> <%= link_to "x", meal_path(meal.id), method: :delete %> </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody class=meal-tbody>

  <%# get reference to current meal and its foods %>
  <%= render meal.meal_foods %>

  <td class=remove-td-center> <%= link_to "new food", foods_path, method: :create %> </td> 
 </tbody>    
</tr>
```

Comment: You might want to add your model definitions in full. Otherwise it's had to figure out the problem. It seems that there is no `has_many` association between `meal` and `meal_foods`.

Comment: ok I've added the models and some extras just in case

Comment: -1 the error message is very clear

Comment: I know what the error is saying.... I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: If you understand what the error message is saying, it's pretty clear how to fix...m

Comment: maybe to you it is clear. To me it was not. I didn't know how to pass parameters from the view to the controller. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. "has_many :meal, dependent: :destroy" should be "has_many :meals, dependent: :destroy"
   has_many association names are pluralized. If you want only one here, use has_one instead.
2. this line is wrong:  @food = current_user.meal.meal_food.build, as meal is a has_many, so you need a "first". Also, it doesn't return a food, but a meal_food, so you should say this, otherwise you are confusing yourself:

   @meal_food = current_user.meal.first.meal_food.build

It occurs to me that for MealFood => a better name would be Serving. Then your meal can have_many servings, and each serving can have a food. Not a mistake, just more understandable. Then you'd have the following code. Note that I didn't see the point in the STI for foods - it makes much more sense to simply put the amount of the food eaten in the servings table, then you don't need the STI at all.

```
  class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :sanitize
    has_many :servings
    has_many :foods, :through => :servings
    attr_accessible :meal_name

    def sanitize
      self.meal_name = "Meal"
    end
  end 


  class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :brand, :carbs, :fat, :name, :protein, :type
    has_many :servings, :inverse_of => :food
  end   

  class Serving < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :amount
    has_many :foods
    has_many :meals
  end 

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :meals, dependent: :destroy
  end
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I will have to implement the servings design as you explained because this design is inherently flawed for what I want to do anyway. 

One question though: What if I'm adding meal_foods to a meal somewhere in the middle between the first and last meal for a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you say User.meal.meal_foods, sometimes you say User.meal.first.meal_foods.  User.meal is an array of Meals, hence from console User.meal.first.meal_foods works, and in your code User.meal.meal_foods gives you no method error.  Also, you should use plural meals in your code and swap out has_many meal with has_many meals.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I made the plural change.

Comment: np.  I was trying to give you the answer without spelling it out verbatim as it's a pretty easy fix - which you actually answered on your own in your question where you state in the console selecting an element of the array worked, but then in your code you try to access the model method on the array of models. See above - "User.meal is an array of Meals, hence from console User.meal.first.meal_foods works, and in your code User.meal.meal_foods gives you no method error."